# Laravel 5.5 Website Give HTTP ERROR 500 While After Registering SocialiteServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I'm new to Laravel and I have a website which I developed in Laravel 5.5. I downloaded Socialite. Now the problem is, If i put the following line in "providers" array in config/app.php for registering SocialiteServiceProvider

```
Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,
```

and adding up the following Facade in "aliases" array,

```
'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
```

The website  gives HTTP 500 error after refreshing the page. Socialite is the only additional package i'm trying to use with my website and rest of the providers came up with Laravel 5.5 installation. I posted this question few days ago on Laracasts but nobody bother to reply.

Please help me out to fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: update your code also

Comment: What error are you receiving? You say you `downloaded` Socialite. Did you install it with `composer`? If not, run `composer dump-autoload -o` in your terminal.

Comment: For most errors my first step usually is I turn on debug (if not already) and check the logs for the error messages or exceptions thrown, and start from there.

Comment: Thanks @fubar, It worked.